# How can I get the name of a color without a lot of if-statements?

Tags: java, string, colors

In a game that I'm making, the teams are named by colors (e.g. RED, BLUE, CYAN). What I'm trying to do right now is get the name of the team that the player is on and draw the player's name and team (to test if everything is working and find bugs). Right now, there is a bug: the player's name isn't colored the same as the team it's actually on. That's where this comes in; if I can draw the name of the team the player is on, I can find where in my code there's a bug by finding the name of the team compared to the color of the player.
This is my code right now that tries to get the name of the team:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team {

    ArrayList<Player> players;
    Color color;

    public Team(ArrayList<Player> players, Color color) {
        this.players = players;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers(){
        return players;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        if(color == Color.red) {
            return "red";
        }
    }

}
```

The only way I could think of accomplishing this would be to repeat the if-statement in the `getName()` method, but that would take a lot of time to loop over and a lot of time to code.

Comment: tried return color.name(); or similar?

Comment: @Stultuske there is no `color.name()` or anything of the sort; the only String is `color.toString()`, which returns `java.awt.Color`.

Comment: sorry, I was assuming you were using an enum. why don't you?

Comment: @Stultuske I don't have much experience with enums and I don't know how I would implement them in this case.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-enum-example/

Comment: those two links should show you all you need

Comment: @Stultuske I can see, but for what would I put the `Enum`? The teams?

Comment: Why do you think it will take a lot of time? There are only a dozen or so colors in `java.awt.Color` - just write the `if` statements or use a `switch`

Comment: for the color, if you really want to just do something like: color.name(); to get the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you cannot compare with `==` as Color is a class, not an enum.
Please use `.equals()` method instead.

Second (from the same reason) you can create a hash table with all known color names and use Color as the hash key.

```
Map<Color, String> knownColorNames; // initialize with all known color names

public String getName() {
    return knownColorNames.getOrDefault(color, "unknown color name");
}
```

You would need to have some default name returned in case color does not have a name assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Use an enum instead of `java.awt.color`:

```
enum Color {
        RED, GREEN, CYAN;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString().toLowerCase();
        }
}
```

In your getName method just return `color.toString()`.
There is no need for a Map or Reflection

Answer (score 1):

As an alternativ to the `enum` approach (which I'd actually favor), you can put the names in a map.

```
class YourClass {
    private static final Map<Color, String> COLOR_NAMES = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        COLOR_NAMES.put(Color.red, "red");
        //
    }

    public static getName(Color color) {
        return COLOR_NAMES.get(color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a map.

```
Map<Color, String> colorNames = new HashMap<>();
```

Then populate the map.

```
colorNames.put(Color.BLUE, "blue");


public String getName(Color c){
    return colorNames.computeIfAbsent(c, key->Long.toHexString(key));
}
```

You could populate the map with a text file, or you could go through the Color class and grab all of the static fields with reflection.

Here is a way to automatically create the mappings using reflection.

```
Map<Color, String> names = new HashMap<>();
Field[] fields = Color.class.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f: fields){
    if(f.getType()==Color.class){
        names.put((Color)f.get(Color.class), f.getName());
    }
}

System.out.println(names.get(Color.YELLOW));
//YELLOW
```

Note that some colors are probably overwritten due to the name conflicts. eg. BLACK and black.

Answer (score 1):

This could help: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/enum/Loop_through_Color_enum_and_printing_values_Different_ways_of_doing_it.htm

I adapted it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class clazz = Color.class;
    Field[] colorFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    HashMap<Color, String> singleColors = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field cf : colorFields) {
      int modifiers = cf.getModifiers();
      if (!Modifier.isPublic(modifiers))
        continue;

      Color c = (Color) cf.get(null);
      if (!singleColors.values().contains(c))
        singleColors.put(c, cf.getName());
    }
    System.out.printnln("My Color: " + getName(Color.BLUE));
  }

  public String getName(Color myColor) {
      for (Color c : singleColors.keySet()) {
          if (c.equals(myColor)) {
              return singleColors.get(c);
          }
       }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection ...

Here is "proof of concept" code:

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Field [] names = Color.class.getFields();
        HashMap<Color,String> list=new HashMap<Color,String>();
        for ( Field name: names ){
                try{
                    list.put((Color)Color.class.getDeclaredField(name.getName()).get(null),name.getName());
                }catch (NoSuchFieldException e){}
            }
            System.out.println( list.get(Color.RED));
            System.out.println( list.get(Color.BLUE));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
RED
BLUE
```

Comment: (Color)f.get(Color.class)?

Answer (score 0):

**switch**
You could use a switch statement. And then just save the name as a variable in the class player when instantiating it.